# Simpler Regular Expression For My Multi-pattern Replacement

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code to address a situation where I need to remove simple json markup:

```
String inputExample = "[\"883-DDEQW\"]";
inputExample = inputExample.replaceAll("]", "");
inputExample = inputExample.replaceAll("\\[", "");
inputExample = inputExample.replaceAll("\"", "");
inputExample = inputExample.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

, so that the resulting string becomes the desired: 883-DDEQW

So 4 lines of code to perform the replace. Is there a simpler (or should I say more concise) way to perform the same operations?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do it as `inputExample = inputExample.replaceAll(...).replaceAll(...)`. But in the end, it's the same ...

Comment: Or use a regex, like `.replaceFirst(".*\"([^"]+)\".*", "$1")`.

Comment: I like the simplicity of ".replaceFirst(".*\"([^"]+)\".*", "$1")", but it did not compile. I really appreciate the response though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the characters you want to replace into a character class:

```
[\]\["\\]
```

As a Java string:

```
"[\\]\\[\"\\\\]"
```

You can pass this to `replaceAll`:

```
inputExample = inputExample.replaceAll("[\\]\\[\"\\\\]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was hoping for. It works and is very simple!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing undesired characters, you can match the desired output. In your case it seems to be sequence of letters, digits and `-`. 
So the pattern might look like this: `[\w\d-]+`

```
@Test
public void testRegexp(){
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\d-]+)");
    final String inputExample = "[\"883-DDEQW\"]";
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputExample);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Result: `883-DDEQW`

Useful tool for testing regular expressions: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

*Update:*

If you know you will get a proper JSON array, you can parse it using some library. Commonly used is google Gson:

```
@Test
public void testJson(){
    final String inputExample = "[\"883-DDEQW\"]";
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(inputExample).getAsJsonArray();
    for (final JsonElement element: jsonArray){
        System.out.println(element.getAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the pattern of characters that will remain are less consistent then the one that need to be removed.

Comment: In that case, it would be best to parse the JSON. I'll update my answer

Comment: the json dependency will disappear at some point soon. I want the code to live in current state without having to change it once the json markup is removed from future input files. That is why I am using the regex.